# How can I get share and download links from OneDrive API

Tags: javascript, onedrive

I am using the OneDrive [JS Picker](https://dev.onedrive.com/sdk/js-v7/js-picker-open.htm#advanced-open-scenarios) and would like to get both a download and share value. The [sample in the documentation](https://dev.onedrive.com/sdk/js-v7/js-picker-open.htm#example-file-picker-options) lists the options for the *action* parameter separated by pipes. I was hoping to use bitwise operators to combine those values (e.g.

```
action: "share | download"
```

but that doesn't seem to allow both the webUrl value and the download url (@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl)... has anybody else been able to do this? Or is there a way to use the share URL (webUrl) to get a download url so we can get the text contents of files?

I know there is a [REST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn659726.aspx) service available though that may be deprecated, given the message at the top of that page:

> This documentation is archived and is not being maintained.

but if that is still usable, perhaps we could use that to download the file... if so, can I put the file id in that download URL and an access token?

Comment: The supported API for REST clients is documented here, https://dev.onedrive.com/README.htm
For details on how to use a share token or share URL consult https://dev.onedrive.com/shares/shares.htm, from this you can download the file via the normal API convensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to host the [OneDrive.js file](https://js.live.net/v7.0/OneDrive.js) locally, un-minify it and modify the line below (line 104) to have the downloadUrl included in all queries on files. That allows us to get a shareUrl and a downloadUrl.

```
e.DEFAULT_QUERY_ITEM_PARAMETER = "expand=thumbnails&select=id,name,size,webUrl,folder,@content.downloadUrl";
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the missleading pipe sign. Actually right now we only allow one action per request like (action: "query"). The pipeline sign in the doc means 'or' in English not in code.

Before my answer, I want to clarify the difference between a webUrl and a shareUrl.

- A webUrl which you see in the response's 'webUrl' attribute is the
  url pointed to the resource online which requires user login to see
  it.
- A shareUrl which contains the permission which everyone who has the
  link could see/edit it based on the user's config.

**JS Picker**

If you want the download link and a webUrl back at the same time, it should be easy:

```
{
    action: "query",
    advanced: {queryParameters: "select=id,name,webUrl,@content.downloadUrl"}
}
```

If you want both the download link and share link back at the same time, it is not supported.

**API**

For using the API to achieve this, you can go to the new API page:  https://dev.onedrive.com/items/get.htm

and get the item with already shared links should be

```
GET /v1.0/drive/items/<item-id>?select=id,name,@content.downloadUrl,webUrl&expand=permissions
```

all already shared links should be returned in the permissions array object.

If you don't have a shared link, and you need to create the shared link, you should try https://dev.onedrive.com/items/sharing_createLink.htm

while it does not return the webUrl and download url back so you need an extra request.

Comment: Alright - I am trying to use the API and it is not clear which root URL/domain to use - would I use `https://api.onedrive.com`, given  [this getting started page](https://dev.onedrive.com/getting-started.htm) ? e.g. https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/items/[item-id]?select=id,name,@content.downloadUrl,webUrl&expand=permissions

Comment: When I try that URL (https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/items/[item-id]?select=id,name,@content.downloadUrl,webUrl&expand=permissions) with an ItemId returned from the picker, I see `{"error":{"code":"itemNotFound","message":"Item does not exist"}}` - I wonder if that is because we didn't include an auth token? If that is necessary,  can get such a token from the OneDrive js var and execute the HTTP request via JS?

Comment: yes, you need a auth token for AAD/MSA for your app: https://apps.dev.microsoft.com

Comment: Per your clarification, yeah I want a shareUrl and noted that it comes via oneDriveItem.permissions[0].link.webUrl... Can I fetch the auth token in the client side, since the user has already authenticated, so as to do the GET request (like you mentioned under the **API** section of your answer) and add the authentication header? I tried looking at the [onedrive explorer example](https://dev.onedrive.com/odx/) but see that it checks the cookies for the token and that would be a different domain ( than ours https://onedrive.live.com, from the picker popup window) in our situation...

Comment: unfortunately, we don't expose the access token to users right now due to security concerns. sorry.

Comment: okay thanks for your response. I think I will add an issue on github because we don't really want the user to have to click twice to authenticate for one service (picking the file, for which we need the shareUrl and the downloadUrl).